# What C# Data Structure Should I Use?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, data-structures, collections

This question pertains to C#, LINQ grouping and Collections.

I'm currently working on a grouping issue and I wanted to get some feedback from the community. I've encountered this particular problem enough times in the past that I'm thinking of writing my own data structure for it. Here are the details:

Suppose you have a grouping that consists of a manufacturer and products and the data structure is grouped by manufacturer. There are many manufacturers and many products. The manufacturers each have a unique name and id. The products may have similar names, but they do have unique ids. The proceeding list represents an example.

Ford 1, Fiesta 1945, Taurus 6413, Fusion 4716, F1 8749,

Toyota 2, Camry 1311, Prius 6415, Corolla 1117, Tacoma 9471

Chevrolet 3, Silverado 4746, Camero 6473, Volt 3334, Tahoe 9974

etc...

The data structure I would use to represent this would be

```
IEnumerable<Manufacturer, ManufacturerID, IEnumerable<Product, ProductID>>
```

but this doesn't exist. So my question I want to ask the community is what data structure would you recommend and why?

Update:

I would like to keep the types anonymous and avoid the dynamic keyword. So the data structure would be something like

`IEnumerable SomeDataStructure<T, U, V>`

The other requirement is that is can have duplicated items. Here's kind of what I'm thinking:

```
public class MyDataStructure<T, U, V>
{
    // make this like a list, not a dictionary
}
```

Update:

I decided to go with a Tuple data structure. It's very powerful and easy to query against. The proceding code is how I ended up using it to create my manufacturer-vehicle relationships. The result is a nicely ordered data structure that has unique manufacturers ordered by name with their associated unique vehicles ordered by name.

```
public class ManufacturersVehicles
{
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleName { get; set; }
}

// "data" actually comes from the database. I'm just creating a list to use a mock structure to query against.
var data = new List<ManufacturersVehicles>
{
    { ManufacturerID = 1, Manufacturer = "Ford", VehicleID = 1945, VehicleName = "Fiesta" },
    { ManufacturerID = 1, Manufacturer = "Ford", VehicleID = 6413, VehicleName = "Taurus" },
    { ManufacturerID = 1, Manufacturer = "Ford", VehicleID = 4716, VehicleName = "Fusion" },
    etc...
};

// Get a collection of unique manufacturers from the data collection and order it by the manufacturer's name.
var manufacturers = data.Select(x => new { ManufacturerID = x.ManufacturerID, ManufacturerName = x.ManufacturerName })
                        .Distinct()
                        .OrderBy(x => x.ManufacturerName)
                        .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.ManufacturerID, x.ManufacturerName, new Dictionary<int, string>()))
                        .ToList();

// Add the manufacturer's vehicles to it's associated dictionary collection ordered by vehicle name.
foreach (var manufacturer in manufacturers)
{
    // Get the collection of unique vehicles ordered by name.
    var vehicles = _alertDetails.Where(x => x.ManufacturerID == manufacturer.Item1)
                                .Select(x => new { VehicleID = x.VehicleID, VehicleName = x.VehicleName })
                                .Distinct()
                                .OrderBy(x => x.VehicleName);

    foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
    {
        manufacturer.Item3.Add(vehicle.VehicleID, vehicle.VehicleName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need one, again? Why not just use an anonymous type?

Comment: How is the data acceed? Do you need to look up a list of products by manufacturer? Or find the manufacturer of a product? Or what?

Comment: I'm using the data to populate a treeview control in asp.net. The data from the database comes back without any grouping and I'd like a data structure to group the data easily for easy access when events cause the data to be filtered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyDataStructure` sounds very similar to a `Tuple`.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383822.aspx) for the three-generic parameter variant.  `Tuple` gives a strongly typed container for a number of specified other types.

Comment: I'm going to play around with this. Here's what I've got: var tuple = new List<Tuple<int, string, Dictionary<int, string>>>();

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. See my lastest edit to see how I used it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I would create a class named Manufacturer:

```
public class Manufacturer
{
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set;}
}
```

Then create a Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

Then use LINQ projection with the Select extension method to create the Manufacturer object.

Comment: It would seem that the question was more about "*LINQ grouping and Collections*" than it was about modeling `Manufacturer` and `Product`.  As you can see in the question, he already has an object model for `Manufacturer` and `Product`.

Comment: I get that but why go through all that trouble for a very specific scenario.  If it's modeled properly you can use LINQ to Objects to format the data how you want (similar to John Saunders question above).

Comment: Exactly, he's asking how to leverage LINQ to Objects to shape his results using his already-created `Manufacturer` and `Product` classes.  You're answer is simply restating his question in a way.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
public class Manufacturer : IEquatable<Manufacturer>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    // ...
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    // ...
}

// groups is of type IEnumerable<IGrouping<Manufacturer, Product>>

var groups = data.GroupBy(row => new Manufacturer(row), row => new Product(row));
```

EDIT:  If you want to use anonymous types (as you mentioned now in your update) then `GroupBy` should work just as well if you construct anonymous objects, instead of declaring a `Manufacturer` and `Product` class as in my sample.

Comment: You show no relation between Manufacturer and Product nor do you have the constructor that takes a "data" element as a parameter in the Linq query. I don't see how this could act as a replacement.

Comment: The relation is implicit in the resulting groups.  The constructor should be trivial but depends on how the data is sourced.  The poster didn't give any detail about that, but I assumed that maybe it's coming from some big table of joined data with manufacturer and product information both contained in a single datum.  In that case, this would be the most straightforward way to associate the manufacturers with products.